# Plupload: Can't upload video iphone ios 8.3

Tags: iphone, video, ios8, plupload

Can't upload video using plupload on ios 8.3 iphone.
**Problem is that I won't get the FilesAdded event.**
Code works fine for image upload on same phone and the code works fine in google chrome on mac.

```
that.videoUploader = new plupload.Uploader({
  browse_button: that.videoUploadBtn.get(0),
  url: 'video-upload'
  runtimes: 'html5,flash',
  flash_swf_url: 'js/Moxie.swf',
  // multiple_queues : false,
  multi_selection : false,
  // max_file_size : '100mb',
  // max_file_count : 1,
  // chunk_size: '200kb',
  // max_retries: 3,
  autostart: true,
  filters : [
    { title : "Image files", extensions : "mp4" }
  ]  
});

that.videoUploader.init();
that.videoUploader.bind('FilesAdded', that.videoHandlePluploadFileSelected);
that.videoUploader.bind('FileUploaded', that.videoHandlePluploadFileUploaded);   

Upload.prototype.videoHandlePluploadFileSelected = function(uploader, file) {
  alert("start upload!");
  uploader.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was the filters-part that messed up everything. Problem solved removing that part.